# Confused about the open/closed set in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. I understand well that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both open and closed sets. I read some notes that say, that $\emptyset$ and $M$ are both open and closed. So, doesn't it only hold if $M=\mathbb{R}$? Why is it necessary to define other than the set $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^{k}$) when we are learning about the metric space? For example $d:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (or $d:\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{k}\to\mathbb{R}$) instead of $d:M\times M\to\mathbb{R}$. I have seen some problems that don't let $M=\mathbb{R}$ which made me doubt.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is not the only set that can have a metric.

Comment: @Mitsos I completely agree. When some notes say that $M$ is both open and closed set, so it must be $M=\mathbb{R}$ in this case, right?

Comment: If the space is connected then the only closed-open sets are the space and the empty set. It doesn't have to be $\mathbb R$. $\mathbb R$ is just a mere example of a metric space. If for example you have the complex numbers and the euclidean metric $(\mathbb C,|.|)$ then $\mathbb R$ is a subset of the last one which is not open (you cannot even draw a disk in $\mathbb R$)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but let me take a stab at it. *Any* metric space denoted $(M,d)$ has $M$ and $\emptyset$ as open and closed sets. Just because $M$ is open and closed does not imply $M=\mathbb{R}$. For instance, we could have $M$ being the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if the space we're looking at is being viewed as a self-contained space, i.e., not a subspace of another space, then the entire space is trivially open.

We know that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is open as a metric space. Now here's the subtlety:

Consider say $M=[0,1]$.  Then $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not an open set. That is, if $M$ is contained in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$, it is closed. However, if we instead treat $[0,1]$ as its own metric space $([0,1],d_{[0,1]})$ where we use the induced metric from $(\mathbb{R},d)$, then the entire space is open.

The space $([0,1], d_{[0,1]})$ is the entire space. It doesn't *live* in $\mathbb{R}$. It is its *own* space.

In terms of a subspace topology, a set is open in the subspace $[0,1]$ if and only if there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $U \cap [0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$. It is thus trivial that $[0,1]$ is both open and closed in $[0,1]$.

Can you see why?

Moreover, we have the property that if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, and if $U$ is open in $Y$, and $Y$ is open in $X$, then $U$ is open in $X$, using the definition that a set is open in the subspace topology if there exists an open set $V \subset X$ so that $U = Y \cap V$.